# How to create a Debian source package with Qt Creator?

Tags: application-development, packaging, qt-creator

What do I need to do to get a package that I can submit to the Ubuntu Software Center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very hard to tell from your question what you already know, so I assume that you:

1. can program
2. in C++
3. with Qt widgets / the QT framework.

As far as I know, the QT Creator is **not** able to create debian packages to submit to the Ubuntu Software Center.

QT Creator **is** able to create debian packages for Maemo5 (see [here](http://wiki.maemo.org/Packaging_Qt_Creator_Apps_for_Maemo_Extras)). Looking through the discussions on Maemo, it seemes that this process is not easily changeable, but maybe you can start from there.

If you are not fixated on QT Creator, you can simply use it to create you code and then follow the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging) to create your debian package.

The actual submission to the Software Center is described [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/).

For future questions I would suggest you write in more detail what your actual problem is.

Comment: Would it also be possible to submit a package to the software center if it's written in Python?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with an additional rule in the makefile generated by qmake:

1. Write a shell script `my_package_script.sh` that creates the package.
2. In your .pro file, add this:

   ```
   mypackagerule.target = mypackagerule
   mypackagerule.command = exec my_package_script.sh
   QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mypackagerule
   ```

Now you can create your package calling `make mypackagerule`. In Qt Creator, you can do that by adding a new (Make) compilation step in the Project tab.