# Developing for ubuntu phone: where is the SDK?

Tags: application-development, development, ubuntu-touch, application-submission

I was quickly reading this [introduction to QML for Ubuntu Phones](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/), now I was honestly expecting something more than that from Canonical.

My questions are:

- where is a real SDK with libs ? All I can see are APIs
- QML really is the alternative to HTML5 apps ? It's basically the same thing without any real benefit.
- there will ever be a true native toolkit with C/C++ toolchains, libs, headers and all the bits and stuff ?
- how to package applications for Ubuntu phones ?
- there is an emulator for the Ubuntu OS for phones ?

Comment: Please add only one question per question. Keep in mind at least one question is speculative and can't be answered, so it is a bad fit for our site.

Comment: @user1849534 please could you mark one of the two answers as an "answer", so this question is no longer "unanswered".

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind that, as stated on the [Go mobile page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/), what is available right now is a developer preview. There are no claims for it to be a full SDK, which it will be at some point, but not yet.

In summary, what is being offered to early adopters at this point is:

- A set of components part of the Ubuntu UI toolkit
- Online (and local) API documentation for all of the released components

With these, you are already equipped to develop and run Ubuntu phone apps on a desktop host machine, and get familiar with the toolkit in time for the full SDK to be released.

Comment: Please update this answer

Answer (score 1):

@user1849534 There **is** now an SDK at http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/.

In terminal, type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

In answer to the other questions:

- QML can be compiled, so it **is** faster.
- C, I believe can be used([Is it possible to write a Mobile app with a engine written in C?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258293/is-it-possible-to-write-a-mobile-app-with-a-engine-written-in-c)).
- [How to create a Debian source package with Qt Creator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63158/how-to-create-a-debian-source-package-with-qt-creator)
- Emulator? Not yet.