# Is it possible to write a Mobile app with a engine written in C?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I am working on a chess engine which is written in C ( ttps://launchpad.net/enpassant) . By the time it is completed, I plan to have different versions for the Desktop and mobile. Now, is it possible for me to have a GUI written with the help of the Ubuntu mobile SDK while uses the C engine internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work since the SDK is based on Qt5 and QtQuick 2.0 you should be able to port (integrate) your C code because you are able to embed C code in C++. Maybe you have to write a Qt wrapper to connect the QML UI with the C backend.